# trait pickling with configure_traits

Tags: enthought, traitsui

I use the first example code from traitsui documentation:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Str, Int
import traitsui

class SimpleEmployee(HasTraits):
    first_name = Str
    last_name = Str
    department = Str

    employee_number = Str
    salary = Int

sam = SimpleEmployee()
sam.configure_traits(filename='/Volumes/FAT/Python/Tests/test.dat')
```

The only change is a filename specification in configure_traits().

1 - When the file is nonexistent, a new file is not created. It would be nice to have such a behavior.

2 - How to create this file? Using

```
import pickle

pickle.dump( sam, open( '/Volumes/FAT/Python/Tests/test.dat', "wb" ) )
```

creates the file

```
ctraits.traits
__newobj__
p0
(c__main__
SimpleEmployee
p1
tp2
Rp3
(dp4
S'salary'
p5
I0
sS'__traits_version__'
p6
S'4.5.0'
p7
sS'first_name'
p8
S''
p9
sS'last_name'
p10
g9
sS'employee_number'
p11
g9
sS'department'
p12
VManagement
p13
sb.
```

with 'Management' as the department (I entered this value in the dialog, of course).

But running again

```
sam.configure_traits(filename='/Volumes/FAT/Python/Tests/test.dat')
```

changing the department field and clicking OK to close the dialog does not change the file content (as it is supposed to do from the doc).

(MacOS X)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was going wrong: configure_traits() should be made to run in modal mode:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Str, Int
from traitsui.api import View, OKCancelButtons

class SimpleEmployee(HasTraits):
    first_name = Str
    last_name = Str
    department = Str

    employee_number = Str
    salary = Int

sam = SimpleEmployee()
sam.configure_traits(filename='/Volumes/FAT/Python/Tests/test.dat',kind='modal')
```

now works OK.

As for my question #1, yes, a new file is created if necessary